# Spring autowired null fields between Tomcat server and Tomcat launched programmatically

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, autowired, spring-transactions

1. I am starting my spring web application through a org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat class in my IntelliJ IDE.
2. Doing some processing among autowired services.
3. At a certain point, the fields of a service are all null.

I can bypass this problem by using public getters of these fields within the class but I'm wondering why.

```
 this.persist.doSomeProcess(); // NullPointerException
```

But:

```
 this.getPersist().doSomeProcess(); // with public MyField getPersist() it works fine
```

The thing is that when I run my project on a normal Tomcat through IntelliJ everything works fine and I don't need public getters.

The version of IntelliJ doesn't matter as it is the case since version of 8 months before.

Here are the two different callstacks I have (left one works on real tomcat), right rise a NPE:
[image: The left one is the callstack that doesn't neet public getters and where fields are not null]

I had this problem since I've put @Transactional annotations instead of programmatic calls with TransactionTemplate.

I am really curious about this thing.

Comment: You are accessing the proxy instead of the real object. The proxy always has `null` fields because it delegates to the actual implementation, using a method will actually pass along the call to the actual implementation. Generally this behavior comes from calling `this.persist` from a `final`method in the class being proxied. Proxies and `final` aren't a good mix. In short remove the `final` keyword or use interface based proxies instead of class based proxies.

Comment: Thanks. But why this difference between the TomcatRunner launched in a main method and a "real" tomcat launch with the war exploded?

Comment: Without seeing the code and full execution I cannot tell. Probably because you are bootstrapping in a different way leading to a different way of creating proxies interfaces based to class based proxies.

Answer (score 0):

I found the origin of the issue.
The fields are null during execution within methods that are not public. Once they are set as public, Spring can wire correctly its Proxy. In the TomcatRunner.

I don't know precisely why with a package private method execution it works on a real Tomcat launched within the IDE.

But for the TomcatRunner, we need to set the methods using fields as public to make it work.

We have the same problem if the methods are final. But in this case, both on real Tomcat and TomcatRunner.

Cheers.